# Adicionar recursos do Laravel em um projeto existente

Tags: php, laravel

Sou novo no mundo PHP e Laravel, porém entrei em um projeto que o time original não tenho contato e estou com uma demanda e não queria colocar na CRON a execução de rotinas de envio de e-mails.

Este projeto não tem os padrões do Laravel, porém alguns recursos entendo serem do Laravel, isso estou deduzindo pelo que encontrei no composer.json que possui a seguinte estrutura.

```js
"require": {
        "slim/slim": "3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.5.3",
        "stavarengo/php-sigep": "dev-master",
        "illuminate/database": "*",
        "tuupola/slim-jwt-auth": "^2.4",
        "illuminate/pagination": "~5.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "sofa/eloquence": "^5.6",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.4",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^2.8",
        "kriswallsmith/buzz": "^0.16.1",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^0.2.3",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
        "php-http/message": "^1.7"
    }
```

Pela documentação do Laravel encontrei as bibliotecas Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule e  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as quais me possibilitariam desenvolver este agendamento de tarefas, estou certo no meu entendimento?

Teria como eu instalar somente esses recursos via composer? Como deveria fazer? Ou poderia adicionar o Laravel ao meu projeto, mas migrar para a estrutura Laravel aos poucos?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Sim você está certo no seu entendimento sobre agendar usando o Schedule do Laravel. Leve em considereção que o Schedule vai precisar de um processo rodando no servidor igual à CRON.

Já que faz o uso do Laravel, seria interessante você usar o framework por completo, não acha? 

Não sou expert em Laravel também, mas acho que o Schedule não vai funcionar sem o "core" do framework.

Comment: Olá Tiago eu iniciei este estudo para colocar completamente no Laravel, mas como essa primeira versão já está em fase de homologação vou precisar criar este agendamento, mas vou seguir seu conselho e neste momento utilizar via CRON.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, pelas dependências desse projeto é feito em [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com), o qual não possui uma biblioteca para agendamentos de tarefas, é necessário a implementação de uma, pesquisando no packagist achei essa https://packagist.org/packages/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler, pode juntá-la ao phpmailer que já está instalado nesse projeto e desenvolver um serviço de agendamento de disparo de e-mails, Não conheço bem o Slim e lamento não poder ajudar mais.

Comment: Agradeço Emmanuel, vou estudar essa possibilidade, quem sabe resolveu meu problema.